# $\mathrm{e}^{-1/x^2}$ real differentiable but not complex differentiable at $x=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

So I was reading about Laurent series and $\mathrm{e}^{-1/x^2}$ was used as an example. We define the function $f(x) = \mathrm{e}^{-1/x^2}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$. Then it was stated that, as a real function, $f(x)$ is infinitely differentiable everywhere, but as a complex function it is not differentiable at $x=0$. Why is this?

We know that $f$ is real differentiable if the derivative exists at every point of its domain.   We have $$f'(x) = -\frac{f(x)}{x^2},$$ so that $f'(0)=0/0$?

It is complex differentiable if $$\lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$$ exists. I guess we have an essential singularity in the argument of the exponential function at $z_0=0$ which is why it is not complex differentiable?

Comment: $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x} = 0$, but $\lim_{y \to 0} \dfrac{e^{-1/(iy)^2}}{iy} = \infty$.

Comment: $f$ is $C^\infty$ and $f^{(k)}(0)  = 0$ for all $k$, but $f$ not identically zero. Any complex function that is differentiable in a ball around zero and has $f^{(k)}(0)  = 0$ for all $k$ must be identically zero.

Comment: Right! I guess I misread the condition for the complex function as implying that $z=0$ instead of just the real part. I thought of this as a possibility but got $$\frac{ \mathrm{e}^{-1/(x+iy)}-\mathrm{e}^{-1/0}  }{ x+iy  }.$$ How did you account for that limit? I see that letting $y=0$ and taking the limit and $x=0$ and taking the limit results in different limits. This is what I tried to do. Thanks! But how about that argument of the exponential?

Comment: To avoid some of your confusion, define $f$ more carefully.  As you have done for $x \ne 0$, but add $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Ah, right. Got it.

Comment: If you're asking why it has derivatives of all orders at $0$ as a function of a real variable, that's the "hard" part.  If you're only asking why it's NOT differentiable at $0$ as a function of a complex variable, that's much easier: just think about what happens to $f(z)$ as $z$ approaches $0$ along the imaginary axis.